# Can`t insert a new record into contacts

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts

I can successfully insert a new record using People.CONTENT_URL according to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html#addingrecord.
But the People class is deprecated, So i would like to using ContentProviderOperation and Data.CONTENT_URL to insert record. here is my code.

```
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ArrayList operations = new ArrayList();
        operations.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValue(Phone.CONTACT_ID, "23").withValue(CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                        "13412341234123412341234").build());
        try {
            getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, operations);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506260/android-contacts-update-note/6535106#6535106

Comment: I think i have done the same with it.

Comment: i find the cause. when  insert a new entry, i must first insert a new RawContacts using ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
         .build());.then use withValueBackReference to get the RawContact_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my understanding, you simply want to add a new contact, right?

I have answered the question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744187/how-to-add-new-contacts-in-android/4744514#4744514). I have used the same piece of code and it works for me.

Comment: Welcome! Please consider voting this answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to add a new contact try this code :

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT); 
        intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);  
        intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, "name"); 
        intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, "123456");  
        startActivity(intent);
```